# Spark accumulator empty when used in UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was working on optimizing my Spark process, and was trying to use a UDF with an accumulator. I have gotten the accumulator to work on its own, and was looking to see if I would get any speed up using a UDF. But instead, when I wrap the accumulator in the UDF, it remains empty. Am I going something wrong in particular? Is there something going on with Lazy Execution where even with my `.count` it is still not executing?

Input:

```
0,[0.11,0.22]
1,[0.22,0.33]
```

Output:

```
(0,0,0.11),(0,1,0.22),(1,0,0.22),(1,1,0.33)
```

Code

```
  val accum = new MapAccumulator2d()
  val session = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  session.sparkContext.register(accum)

  //Does not work - Empty Accumlator
  val rowAccum = udf((itemId: Int, item: mutable.WrappedArray[Float]) => {
    val map = item
      .zipWithIndex
      .map(ff => {
        ((itemId, ff._2), ff._1.toDouble)
      }).toMap
    accum.add(map)
    itemId
  })
  dataFrame.select(rowAccum(col("itemId"), col("jaccardList"))).count

  //Works
  dataFrame.foreach(f => {
    val map = f.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Float]](1)
      .zipWithIndex
      .map(ff => {
        ((f.getInt(0), ff._2), ff._1.toDouble)
      }).toMap
    accum.add(map)
  })

  val list = accum.value.toList.map(f => (f._1._1, f._1._2, f._2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only issue here is using `count` to "trigger" the lazily-evaluated UDF: Spark is "smart" enough to realize that the `select` operation can't change the result of `count` and therefore doesn't really execute the UDF. Choosing a different operation (e.g. `collect`) shows that the UDF works and updates the accumulator.

Here's a (more concise) example:

```
val accum = sc.longAccumulator

val rowAccum = udf((itemId: Int) => { accum.add(itemId); itemId })

val dataFrame = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).toDF("itemId")

dataFrame.select(rowAccum(col("itemId"))).count()   // won't trigger UDF
println(s"RESULT: ${accum.value}") // prints 0

dataFrame.select(rowAccum(col("itemId"))).collect() // triggers UDF 
println(s"RESULT: ${accum.value}") // prints 15
```

Comment: it worked. But collect feels very aggressive. I am using accumulators to literally avoid using collect. Am I paranoid about this?

Comment: Oh, no - you should definitely NOT use collect in any production code on actual datasets; I merely used it to demonstrate the behavior; Is there no other action performed on your dataframe? If so, I'm afraid using an accumulator is somewhat of an _abuse_ - it's meant to be used for side-effects (and is not as robust and resilient as using DataFrame transformations). Perhaps if the question is actually re how to optimize the alternative - we'll need to see the code for the alternatives you've tried (`groupBy` followed by `collectAsMap`?)

Comment: Well here is the actual problem I was trying to solve before I went down this rabbit hole. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502656/spark-block-matrix-multiplication-scales-poorly