# Spark Block Matrix Multiplication scales poorly

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run the following matrix multiplication in Spark. I have one matrix that is 250k rows by 30k columns. The other(right) is 30k by 30k. While something like tensorflow is able to get through this in about 5 mins, I am getting out of memory and garbage collection errors with Spark.

```
rdd.toBlockMatrix
  .multiply(rightRdd.toBlockMatrix)
  .toIndexedRowMatrix()
```

is there particular tuning I  can perform to be able to complete this?

Comment: You might want to try broadcasting the 30k x 30k matrix.

Comment: I get out of heap space when trying to collect it...

Comment: What are you really trying to do? For what purpose are you calling collect? Have you tried doing a foreach on the result instead, thus processing it row-by-row?

Comment: I am really trying to do the above operation. I was trying to use the collect to multiply a local matrix as the right matrix instead, `.toBlockMatrix.toLocalMatrix`

Comment: Then have you tried what I suggested? Take each row of the matrix product and multiply it with the local matrix? That way, you never have to try to materialize the entire product matrix.

Comment: I can not generate the "local" matrix. In this example rightRdd. It is dense, and 30k by 30k. I will updatte with more examples of what i tried

Comment: what is the size of each block? I think you'll be able to increase your parallelism by making each block smaller and increasing the number of executers