# Creating column types for schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file that I read from and parse to create a dataframe. However, the columns `amount` and `code` should be IntegerTypes. Here's what I have:

```
def getSchema: StructType = {
        StructType(Seq(
          StructField("carrier", StringType, false),
          StructField("amount", StringType, false),
          StructField("currency", StringType, false),
          StructField("country", StringType, false),
          StructField("code", StringType, false),
        ))
      }

  def getRow(x: String): Row = {
    val columnArray = new Array[String](5)
    columnArray(0) = x.substring(40, 43)
    columnArray(1) = x.substring(43, 46)
    columnArray(2) = x.substring(46, 51)
    columnArray(3) = x.substring(51, 56)
    columnArray(4) = x.substring(56, 64)
    Row.fromSeq(columnArray)
  }
```

Because I have `Array[String]` defined, the columns can only be StringTypes and not a variety of both String and Integer. To explain in detail my problem, here's what happens:

First I create an empty dataframe:

```
  var df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], getSchema)
```

Then I have a for loop that goes through each file in all the directories. Note: I need to validate every file and cannot read all at once.

```
for (each file parse):
  df2  = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.textFile(inputPath)
    .map(x => getRow(x)), schema)
df = df.union(df2)
```

I now have a complete dataframe of all the files. However, columns `amount` and `code` are StringTypes still. How can I make it so that they are IntegerTypes?

Please note: I cannot cast the columns during the for-loop process because it takes a lot of time. I'd like to keep the current structure I have as similar as possible. At the end of the for loop, I could cast the columns as IntegerTypes, however, what if the column contains a value that is not an Integer? I'd like for the columns to be not NULL.

Is there a way to make the 2 specified columns IntegerTypes without adding a lot of change to the code?

Comment: You could type cast at **end of `for` loop** using a **`UDF`**, wherein you can **handle non-integer values** (*ceoerce them to `null`*)

Comment: I don't want to coerce them to null. The fields should be not null

Comment: Quoting from your question `..At the end of the for loop, I could cast the columns as IntegerTypes, however, what if the column contains a value that is not an Integer? ..` If you have to have *non null fields*, only option is to **convert non-integers into default values**, which may or may not be acceptable to down-the-line *data analysis*

Comment: @y2k-shubham hmm I wanted to do some error handling where I could indicate which files contains the bad (null)values

Comment: You might want to use `accumulator` along with `UDF`; but beware of *gotchas* like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500616/spark-accumulator-empty-when-used-in-udf). Honestly I'm no expert here, so keep looking. Do care to post an answer once you arrive at a solution / workaround.

Answer (score 2):

What about using datasets?

First create a case class modelling your data:

```
case class MyObject(
    carrier: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    country: String,
    code: Int)
```

create an other case class wrapping the first one with additional infos (potential errors, source file):

```
case class MyObjectWrapper(
                      myObject: Option[MyObject],
                      someError: Option[String],
                      source: String
                      )
```

Then create a parser, transforming a line from your file in myObject:

```
object Parser {
  def parse(line: String, file: String): MyObjectWrapper = {
    Try {
      MyObject(
        carrier = line.substring(40, 43),
        amount = line.substring(43, 46).toDouble,
        currency = line.substring(46, 51),
        country = line.substring(51, 56),
        code = line.substring(56, 64).toInt)
    } match {
      case Success(objectParsed) => MyObjectWrapper(Some(objectParsed), None, file)
      case Failure(error) => MyObjectWrapper(None, Some(error.getLocalizedMessage), file)
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, parse your files:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ds = files
  .filter( {METHOD TO SELECT CORRECT FILES})
  .map( { GET INPUT PATH FROM FILES} )
  .map(path => spark.read.textFile(_).map(Parser.parse(_, path))
  .reduce(_.union(_))
```

This should give you a Dataset[MyObjectWrapper] with the types and APIs you wish.

Afterwards you can take those you could parse:

```
ds.filter(_.someError == None)
```

Or take those you failed to parse (for investigation):

```
ds.filter(_.someError != None)
```

Comment: Hmm, how can I make the fields not null?

Comment: I edited my previous answer taking into account your questions on "how to handle null values or bad integer values" and "how to trace which file these errors came from".